# Sending a grid in a C# class method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here is the problem. I have to do a wpf project where I draw geometrical shapes. I used xaml to draw my shapes but I want their size to be generated randomly. For example a square : I have a class square that has an init() method to generate the square value, and a class draw(). But I don't know what to put in the draw method, I thought using GridName.Height = value but I can't access the GridName. Is there a way to have it in the method, here is the code :

```
   `public void Dessin() { }

    public void Init() {
        Random Rand = new Random();
        float randomFloat = (float)Rand.NextDouble();
        randomFloat = randomFloat * 10;
        UneValeur = randomFloat;
    }`
```

and here is the xaml :

```
 <Grid Name="Page2" Visibility="Hidden" Background="#FF373030">
        <Grid x:Name="Forme" Height="300" Width="300" Margin="255,60,238.333,60.667">
            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Visibility="Visible"/>
        </Grid>
        <Label Name ="LblTest" Content="L'aire de l'ellipse est égale à" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,295,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="36" Width="275" Background="#FFE9DBDB" FontSize="15"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Put the shapes in a Canvas, then set the Width, Height and similar properties of the shape object. Add the shapes to the Chuildren collection of the Canvas, or better, use an ItemsControl like shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031206/1136211

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean, I'm a C# beginner. I don't understand how to create a children collection of that canvas. And how should I pass it in my Dessin Function as a parameter.  If I try to put System.Windows.Shapes or System.Windows.Control it doesn't work.

Comment: You don't have to create it, it is already there. Before trying to continue, read an introductory book about WPF, and perhaps also one about C#. Without a basic understanding of the core concepts you are lost and will never be able to write a decent WPF application.