# WPF How to binding with lineGeometry?

Tags: wpf

I create a drawing application with WPF(using MVVM approach). And I found [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031206/10184747)

This answer is perfect for me. However, I want to draw with LineGeometry.

So I added the following code.

```
vm.ShapeItems.Add(
    new ShapeItem
    {
        Geometry = new LineGeometry(new Point(50,50), new Point(90,90)),
        Fill = Brushes.Red
    });
```

But the red line is not visible. What shoud I do to draw the red line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is very simple, for `LineGeometry` use please `Stroke` property.

```
new ShapeItem
            {
                Geometry = new LineGeometry(new Point(50, 50), new Point(90, 90)),
                Stroke = Brushes.Red,
            }
```

Comment: Thank you answer! Your solution is perfect and very simple! I forgot `Stroke` property.